# Mixed integer formulation of union of polytopes?

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, polyhedra, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

Given $t$ different unbounded polyhedra $P_1:A^{(1)}x^{(1)}\leq b^{(1)},\dots,P_t:A^{(t)}x^{(t)}\leq b^{(t)}$ we are looking for the representation of $\bigcup_{i=1}^tP_i$ (not their convex hull) with mixed integer programming.

1. What is the standard way to do this by mixed integer programming with fewest number of additional integer variables?
2. When is it possible do this with only $O(t^\alpha)$ additional integer variables where $\alpha\in(0,1)$?

I found some review where they say we can do this with $O(\log t)$ integer variables if the polyhedra have a common recession cone.

3. How is it done when the polytopes have common recession cone with $O(\log t)$ integer variables?

Comment: Optimization over unions of polytopes is called disjunctive programming -- here's a reference: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470400531.eorms0262